# Unexpected '{' in field name when doing string formatting using latex in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to insert text inside a latex equation which is  actually a title for the plot. In other words, the following is the python code for the title I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=8
plt.title(r"Actual time-series is $Y_t=\alpha^\top X_t + \beta^\top X_{t-{0}}$".format(x))

plt.show()
```

The following is the error I received when I implemented the above code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "switch_systems.py", line 419, in <module>
     plt.title(r"Actual time-series is $Y_t=\alpha^\top X_t + \beta^\top  X_{t-{0}}$".format(x)
   ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

I want my title to look like `Actual time-seris is $Y_t=\alpha^\top X_t + \beta^\top  X_{t-8}$`, as in the text inside latex to be exactly resemble what it would have looked like had it been written in latex. Is there a trick to do this?

Comment: ["If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the literal `{` that you want to keep in the text by doing `{{` and `}}`

```
r"Actual time-series is $Y_t=\alpha^\top X_t + \beta^\top X_{{t-{0}}}$".format(8)
```

results in

```
Actual time-series is $Y_t=\alpha^\top X_t + \beta^\top X_{t-8}$
```